# Identifying values from one database to use in another database

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a project in which I need to work with 2 databases, identify values from one database to use in another.

I have a dataframe 1,

```
df1<-data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3),"Condition A"=c("B","B","A"),"Condition B"=c("1","1","2"),"Year"=c(2002,1988,1995))
```

and a dataframe 2,

```
df2 <- data.frame("Condition A"=c("A","A","B","B"),"Condiction B"=c("1","2","1","2"),"<1990"=c(20,30,50,80),"1990-2000"=c(100,90,80,30),">2000"=c(300,200,800,400))
```

I would like to add a new column to df1 called "Value", in which, for each ID (from df1), collects the values from column 3,4 or 5 from df2 (depending on the year), and following conditions A and B available in both databases. The end result would be something like this:

```
df1<-data.frame("ID"=c(1,2,3),"Condition A"=c("B","B","A"),"Condition B"=c("1","1","2"),"Year"=c(2002,1988,1995),"Value"=c(800,50,90))
```

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can simply `left_join`, then `mutate` with `case_when`, then drop the undesired columns with `select`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, by=c("Condition.A", "Condition.B"))%>%
  mutate(Value=case_when(Year<1990 ~ X.1990,
                         Year<2000 ~ X1990.2000,
                         Year>=2000 ~ X.2000))%>%
  select(-starts_with("X"))

  ID Condition.A Condition.B Year Value
1  1           B           1 2002   800
2  2           B           1 1988    50
3  3           A           2 1995    90
```

EDIT: I edited your code, removing the "Condiction" typo

Comment: Now I can see it also. Bravo+1.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
  rename(Condition.B = Condiction.B) %>% 
  pivot_longer(matches("\\d+{4}")) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = c("Condition.A", "Condition.B")) %>% 
  filter(name == case_when(
    Year < 1990 ~ "X.1990",
    Year > 2000 ~ "X.2000",
    TRUE        ~ "X1990.2000")) %>% 
  select(ID, Condition.A, Condition.B, Year, Value = value) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     ID Condition.A Condition.B  Year Value
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 B           1            2002   800
2     2 B           1            1988    50
3     3 A           2            1995    90
```

- At first we rename the misspelled column `Condiction.B` of `df2` and bring it into a "long format" based on the "<1990", "1990-2000", ">2000" columns. Note that those columns can't be named like this, they are automatically renamed to `X.1990`, `X1990.2000` and `X.2000`.
- Next we use a right join with `df1` on the two `Condition` columns.
- Finally we filter just the matching years based on a hard coded `case_when` function and do some clean up (selecting and arranging).

Comment: Your solution is better. More straight.!

Comment: But GuedesBF wins the game (deserved).

Answer (score 2):

We could do it this way:

1. Condiction must be a typo so I changed it to `Condition`
2. in df1 create a helper column that assigns each your to the group which is a column name in df2
3. bring df2 in long format
4. finally apply `left_join` by `by=c("Condition.A", "Condition.B", "helper"="name")`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(helper = case_when(Year >=1990 & Year <=2000 ~"X1990.2000",
                            Year <1990 ~ "X.1990",
                            Year >2000 ~ "X.2000"))

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols=starts_with("X")
  )

df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by=c("Condition.A", "Condition.B", "helper"="name")) %>% 
  select(-helper)
```

```
  ID Condition.A Condition.B Year value
1  1           B           1 2002   800
2  2           B           1 1988    50
3  3           A           2 1995    90
```